# pythonic method to find the inner value of a list

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have the task to either return the element of a list if there is only one element in it, or to return the list itself. The method I am using works for most of my use cases but not for strings.

```
def inner_value(somelist):
    '''
    Return somelist[0] if it's a one-element list or the whole list otherwise

    :param list somelist: list that might contain only one element
    :returns: element of somelist or somelist

    >>> inner_value([42])
    42
    >>> inner_value([42,43])
    [42, 43]
    >>> inner_value([[42]])
    42
    >>> inner_value([[42,43]])
    [42, 43]
    >>> inner_value('spam')
    'spam'
    >>> inner_value(['spam'])
    'spam'
    >>> inner_value(['spam','eggs','bacon'])
    ['spam', 'eggs', 'bacon']

    .. warning::
       This method does not work for dictionaries (KeyError)
       or single character strings (infinite recursion)!

    '''
    try:
        if len(somelist) == 1:
            return inner_value(somelist[0])
        else:
            return somelist
    except TypeError:
        return somelist
```

Is there a better way of doing it such that
`inner_value('spam') == 'spam'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the variable type using `isinstance` method:

```
if isinstance(somelist, list):
    if len(somelist) == 1:
        return somelist[0]
    else:
        return somelist
else:
    return somelist
```

If you only check the len, it would cause problems, since len would give the size of string too:

```
>>> len(['first','second','third'])
3
>>> len('arbitrary')
9
```

Comment: Ah! That's good. This also gets me around using the try except block for a TypeError. I had the impression that try/except is more pythonic than type testing but of course here this makes it less robust. Interesting!